# jquery Vertical Sliding Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

trying to implement menu from :[this tutorial](http://mediaformations.com/vertical-sliding-menu-with-jquery/), but dont know how to make when one submenu is toogle open to automaticly closed himself when another is toogle open.
thx

Answer (score 0):

you can use a selector to get "Not This", on the this.click event which will return all of the other menus and will allow you to close them.

Supplying some source code will probably get you a better answer.

Comment: thx for trying to help.Code is on the link posted in question.

Comment: so you've copied and pasted the exact html and code from that link and tried to implement it and its not working?

Comment: menu is working like in tutorial, changed css and html, but dont touch id's and classes needed by js.

Answer (score 0):

You could close all open toggles before the new one is opened.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    hideMenus();

    $('.toggle').click(function(){
        var menu = $(this);
        hideMenus();

        if (menu.hasClass('toggle-open')) {     
            menuHide(menu);
        }else{
            menuShow(menu);
        }
    });
});
function hideMenus(){
    $('.toggle').each(function(){
        menuHide($(this));
    });
}

function menuHide(menu){ 
    menu.removeClass('toggle-open').addClass('toggle-closed').empty('').append('+').parents('li').children('ul').slideUp(250); 
    menu.parent('.menutop').removeClass('menutop-open').addClass('menutop-closed'); 
} 
function menuShow(menu){ 
    menu.parent('.menutop').removeClass('menutop-closed').addClass('menutop-open'); 
    menu.removeClass('toggle-closed').addClass('toggle-open').empty('').append('–').parents('li').children('ul').slideDown(250); 
}
```

Comment: tried this, copy code you gave me, and now all toogle are open, and have no ability to closed them.

Comment: There was an error in the code i posted.  It should be fixed now.

Comment: Thx for trying to help, i just insert your code, but dont work.In internet explore all menus are expanded and menu dont respond to click, in other browsers menu work same as in tutorial(dont toogle closed, when other submenu is toogle open.